# Nscurl result , what could be reasons of failing TLSv3 when not using --bg , when i use API to execute the request it pass?

Tags: macos, security, macos-monterey

Nscurl result below, what could be reasons of failing TLSv3 when not using --bg , when i use API to execute the request TLSv3 test pass?
could it mean that i'm running behind some sort of proxy  which terminating TLS/SSL?

when i run
`nscurl  --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://linkedin.com`

here is the result

```
Starting ATS Diagnostics

Configuring ATS Info.plist keys and displaying the result of HTTPS loads to https://linkedin.com.
A test will "PASS" if URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: returns a nil error.
================================================================================

Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection
ATS Dictionary:
{
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Allowing Arbitrary Loads

---
Allow All Loads
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true;
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
        };
    };
}
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A96FFD17-D247-493F-BD95-4F4FACC5AD19>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <A96FFD17-D247-493F-BD95-4F4FACC5AD19>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003afb780 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}
---

---
TLSv1.2
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions for linkedin.com

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions and allowing insecure HTTP for linkedin.com

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Allowing Insecure HTTP
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <920F8738-4506-40F5-B787-25B1D25B8A12>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <920F8738-4506-40F5-B787-25B1D25B8A12>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003ac0ff0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}
---

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <49117A20-915C-416B-A10D-BE4DD4645C3F>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <49117A20-915C-416B-A10D-BE4DD4645C3F>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://linkedin.com/, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003ac3b10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns}}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816}
---

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================
```

when i run
`nscurl -bg  --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://linkedin.com`

here's the result for it

```
Starting ATS Diagnostics

Configuring ATS Info.plist keys and displaying the result of HTTPS loads to https://linkedin.com.
A test will "PASS" if URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: returns a nil error.
================================================================================

Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection
ATS Dictionary:
{
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Allowing Arbitrary Loads

---
Allow All Loads
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true;
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.2
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions for linkedin.com

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions and allowing insecure HTTP for linkedin.com

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Allowing Insecure HTTP
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed for linkedin.com

---
TLSv1.3 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.3";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "linkedin.com" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================
```

Running this command will perform ATS diagnostics for the given URL and provide detailed information about the ATS configuration and the result of the connection attempt. It will indicate whether the connection is successful or if any ATS-related errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

The error message provided indicates that an SSL error occurred while attempting to establish a secure connection to "https://linkedin.com". Here is a breakdown of the error details:

```
Error Domain: NSURLErrorDomain
Error Code: -1200
Error Description: An SSL error has occurred, and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
NSErrorFailingURLKey: The URL that caused the error (https://linkedin.com/ in this case).
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion: A suggestion to connect to the server anyway (prompting user confirmation).
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey: Indicates the stream error domain (value of 3 indicates the SSL error domain).
_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey: The specific task (LocalDataTask <A96FFD17-D247-493F-BD95-4F4FACC5AD19>.<1>) associated with the error.
_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey: Additional related tasks associated with the error.
NSUnderlyingError: The underlying error with more detailed information.
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey: The error code within the stream error domain (-9816 indicates an SSL error).
This error suggests that there was a problem establishing a secure connection with the LinkedIn server, likely due to SSL/TLS configuration or compatibility issues. It's possible that the server's SSL certificate is invalid, expired, or not trusted by the client. It could also be caused by a mismatch in supported SSL/TLS versions or cipher suites between the client and server.
```